# Flutter: How do you wrap a long Row inside a Column into multiple lines

Tags: flutter

How can I wrap multiple Widgets inside a Row to act like a single Widget?

```
widget order:
Column -> Row -> Widgets
```

**Here is the snippet of my code:**

```dart
Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(
                  'To prevent possible overflow, this particularly long text should be properly wrapped and formatted.'),
              Text(
                  'To prevent possible overflow, this particularly long text should be properly wrapped and formatted.'),
              Text(
                  'To prevent possible overflow, this particularly long text should be properly wrapped and formatted.'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your desire UI, it will be a single `Text` widget. You can concatenate the string like `$data1 $data2`, it will merge the text.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
   Text('yourText')
```

If you have multiple textStyle, you can use RichText widget.

Find more about [String](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String-class.html) and [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i know this answer must be confusing but i find a way to do it

```
String desc ="To prevent possible overflow, this particularly long text should be properly wrapped and formatted.";

Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Text(desc),
              Text(desc),
              Text(desc),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

creating a variable to the desc will automatically manage the overflow